# Difficulties with creating an offline Folium map in Python 3.10

Tags: python-3.x, folium

I've been asked to write a simple map application in Python.
The users should be able to create a driving route and place markers on the interactive map - I've heard that Folium is a good choice so I went with that.

However, I'm having problems figuring out how to load maps offline (of a certain area).
I've searched and tried lots of different tools to download the map tiles but still couldn't figure out how to put it back together and display the map properly.

So far I've tried loading the wanted area when connected to the ethernet and saving the html page - this has resulted in downloading some map tiles in the form of PNGs but I couldn't get Folium to display those map tiles properly when offline (Some map tiles were missing, others didn't match the zoom level - a whole mess).

I've also tried downloading map tiles from [MapTiler](https://www.maptiler.com/data/) in the form of MBTiles file. Googling it I understood it's related to SQL DB files but couldn't figure out how extract the map tiles to use in Folium.

Thanks for any help, suggestions are welcome!

Edit: After some more playing with Folium , I've been able to display a map using MBTiles but it still behaves strangely - when zooming in/out some tiles (that should be included in the file) are not being rendered at all. I'll continue digging into this issue aswell as looking for an alternative library.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you download all the map data needed for offline usage, and then just integrate your python app with the data. I suggest using OpenStreetMap

[Download Guide](https://mapscaping.com/how-to-download-data-from-open-street-map-a-complete-guide/)

You can pick which countries/areas you want to download

[image]

you can even refine the map you want via

[image]

you will require to install QuickOSM, you can access it via [python library, related SO question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/351760/calling-a-plugin-quickosm-from-a-python-standalone-application)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I've managed to download the tile set of the area I wanted. However, I run into the following difficulties: I am trying to display them using folium in the following format : path_to_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg  I've seen a few examples of using folium.TileLayer using this format but couldn't get it to display anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Becker sadly not.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? I am in the same position but trying to create offline map on a closed network without internet access. If you got it working, could you paste your code for future googlers to find?